# Python Django - Accessing foreignkey data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to get data from my models with ForeignKey relationships. I have the following models.py:

```
class wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    description = models.TextField()

class collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

class collection_detail(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(collection)
    wine = models.ForeignKey(wine)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    bottle_size = models.ForeignKey(bottle_size)
```

Wine is a basic table, Collection Detail is a table that references a wine and adds user specific data (like price paid) to it. Collection is a group of collection_detail objects.

I am struggling on how to access data within these models. I can easily display data from a specific model, but when viewing a particular collection, I cannot access the collection_detail.wine.name data. Do I need to write specific queries to do this? Can I access this data from the templating language? My data model appears correct when viewed via the admin, I can add the data and relationships I need.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A collection contains many collection_detail. So there is not a single detail to access, but a list. To obtain the queryset of this list use collection.collection_detail_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collection_detail_set` to obtain a queryset of all `collection_detail`'s with that `collection`.

If you want a one-to-one relationship instead of a one-to-many (which is what you get using `ForeignKey`), change

```
collection = models.ForeignKey(collection)
```

to

```
collection = models.OneToOneField(collection)
```

and access the `collection`'s `collection_detail` simply by calling `collection_detail` from your `collection` model.

Comment: Thanks guys! Using the shell I tried the following:

mycollections = collection.objects.filter(user=1)  #get's only my user's collections

mycollection = mycollections.objects.filter(id=1) #grab the first collection

but then I run into trouble... I try:

mydetails = mycollection.collection_detail_set.all()

and I get an error: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'collection_detail_set'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I think I need a one to many relationship since I need to have many "collection_detail" objects per "collection" right?

Comment: `.filter` returns a QuerySet (a set of model instances). This is useful if you have multiple objects with the same parameter (such as quantity = 5). This means you have to use `mycollection = mycollections.objects.filter(id=1)[0]`. A better way to access objects by its primary key, is to use `.get`, i.e. `mycollection = mycollections.objects.get(pk=1)`. This will return a model intance instead of a QueryObject.

Comment: And yes - if you need multiple "collection_detail" objects, you are correct to use one-to-many relationship.